# Axios выполняет два запроса по post

Tags: javascript, axios

Доброго времени суток есть скрипт, который постит новость в базу, к нему при помощи AXIOS пробрасываются данные.

```
saveNews (state, payload) {
  console.log('saveNews' + Date())
  const postFile = 'http://localhost:3000/sys/api/news/addNews.php'
  axios.post(postFile, payload)
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response.data)
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error)
  })
}
```

На стороне сервера сейчас написал для проверки:

```
$id = time();
echo json_encode($id);
file_put_contents('test.txt', 'id - ' . $id . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
```

Так вот, в консоле появляется запись о единократном выполнении функции `saveNews` однако на стороне сервера выполняются, то одна то два вызова файла, которые выполняют запись в файл. 
Что интересно, если выполнять `axios.get()` этого же файла таких проблем нет, в чем подвох?

записи `test.txt`:

```
id - 1535312014
id - 1535312014
id - 1535313073
id - 1535313073
id - 1535313080
id - 1535313080
id - 1535313088
id - 1535313088
```

Явно запросы ежесекундные.

Comment: А вы смотрели во вкладке "Network"? Сколько там запросов. Проверьте, возможно первый выполняется методом `OPTIONS`. На стороне сервера помимо времени логируйте еще и пришедшие данные. Возможное решение - поменять `Content-Type` на `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: Да, по network выполняет два запроса. Интересно, что после `JSON.stringify(payload)` запрос стал выполнятся один раз. Думаю это решение проблемы, но что то понять не могу почему, нигде не видел требований.